# How to properly Show Code Snippets in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, syntax-highlighting

I want to show code snippets with the original formatted styles in Microsoft Word document, is there anyway to do this?

The code is:

```
<iframe class="codetidy" type="text/html" width="100%" src="http://codetidy.com/paste/embed/6130" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387453/best-way-to-show-code-snippets-in-word):

> 1. go to "insert" tab, click "object" button (it's on the right)
> 2. choose "openDocument Text" which will open a new embedded word document
> 3. copy and paste your code from Visual Studio / Eclipse inside this embedded word page
> 4. save and close
>
> The result looks very nice. Here are the advantages of this method:
>
> - the code keeps its original layout and colors
> - the code is separated from the rest of the document, as if it was a picture or a chart
> - spelling errors won't be highlighted in the code (this is cool!)
>
> And it takes only few seconds.

*Note of mine (after checking this solution), just to clear: 
After inserting the object Word will open a new instance, which is the code snippet. Just paste the code, save and close.
If you will want to edit the code just double-click the snippet and Word will open the document.*

You may also consider the other solutions which were presented by other users for this question.

This solution is good for any kind of snippet.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by pressing on <kbd>Prnt Scr</kbd> which will take print screen of your code.

Comment: Yeah. But he wouldn't be able to edit the code within word. No so convenient.